# Deleting an object property has effect before the delete action

Tags: javascript

I've this code :

```
data["id"] = 0;                                                     
console.log(data); // first log
found["test"] = data;
delete data.id;
console.log(data); // second log
```

where data and found is objects created before.

My console print two times the data objects without the "id" properties.

If i replace the delete with : `data.id = '';` the console print two times the data object with an empty id property.

Also the `found["test"]` has the object without the id ( or with id = "" depending which experiment I'm in )

Could someone help me understand what's happening ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: I was indeed using Chrome, but firefox give me the exact same result :(

Comment: @d.zOid: It's because both consoles will only evaluate the object once you expand it, not before.  And by that time, it's already been deleted.  Try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `console.log` is playing tricks on you. The variable `data` is unchanged. The *object* referenced by the variable `data` is what's changing.  Your log will show the state of the obejct when you click on it, not when it's logged.

It's not that the `delete` is happening early, it's that your browser console is opening the object up too late.

If you insert a `debugger` statement to pause execution, you should see what you expect to see.  Then continue execution, and the property will get deleted as you expect.

```
data["id"] = 0;                                                     
console.log(data); // first log
debugger;
// inspect your object now

found["test"] = data;
delete data.id;
console.log(data); // second log
// inspect the object now, the property should be gone
```

---

O you could change what you are logging by drilling into the object:

```
data["id"] = 0;                                                     
console.log(data.id); // 0
found["test"] = data;
delete data.id;
console.log(data.id); // undefined
```